# Does the word "otherwise" disregard the sentence before it or include it?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, usage

I filled out a form for permission to use a branding logo.

The reply I received was something like the following:
"You may use the icon only if it (does a specific something A). Otherwise, as a matter of policy we ask that you (do a specific something B with the icon)."

In this case, does this "otherwise" mean that:

1. If the icon does not do A, I must do B? OR
2. The icon must do A, and I **also** must do B?

Which would it be...?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence means:

- If the icon does A, you may use it.
- If it **does not A**, you **may not use it**.  Because they say "*only* if", sometimes spelled out formally as "if and *only if*" or written in papers as "iff".

Starting a sentence with "otherwise" means that "unless one of the things I just mentioned happens, then..."  It doesn't have to be an "if".  You could say, "Get in the car now, otherwise I'm leaving without you."  There can be multiple choices, and *otherwise* covers everything else: "Drive yourself or take the bus, otherwise you will not get there in time."  In this case they could be more clear, since their first sentence covered all possibilities, leaving no "otherwise".  I would interpret it to mean,

- If it **does not A** then you must to B.

If option B includes using it, then their wording is poor.